# On the applicability of the CLT when the underlying distribution is unknown?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

The Central Limit Theorem (CLT) applies to any probability distribution, *provided* that it has finite variance.

In everyday *practical* statistics, however, the CLT is often (almost always?) invoked in situations where the "underlying distribution" is *unknown*.

I see no a priori reason to expect that such an unknown distribution will have finite variance.  (In particular, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2402282/13675).)  Therefore, I see no a priori justification for such extensive reliance on the CLT.

What's wrong with my reasoning here?

---

Importantly, methods that are based on invalid assumptions of normality can result in spectacular failures (resulting for underestimation of the probability of rare events).

Comment: From the frequentist point of view, where I suspect an appeal to the CLT is more likely to appear, your reasoning seems fine - and I don't know how they would go about it justifying using the CLT without becoming a wee bit Bayesian, i.e. a priori the unknown distribution is contained in the class of distributions with such and such a moment condition.

Comment: Then, I misinterpreted the last part, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One should not seek an *a priori* reason; rather the reason should be sought in the nature of each case separately. Suppose, for example, that you're talking about weights of hamsters. It is reasonable in practice to assume that the distribution of those weights not only has finite variance but is of such a form that convergence in the CLT will not be slow.